# MvvmCross 5.x Datadriven or Codedriven Navigation

Tags: navigation, mvvmcross, data-driven

The ViewModel is responsible for UI logic, including Navigation.
All of the examples show the `Navigate` method being invoked as the result of a user action, typically a button tap, in a Command method.
The `Initialize` method is where 'heavy lifting', like loading data from a database is supposed to be done.
Assume an app like an email reader.  The 'master' view shows a RecyclerList, the user taps an entry to see the detail.

Question:
If a condition in the data (for example, finding only 0 or 1 rows) dictates that a different screen should be displayed (not the list associated with this ViewModel), *how does the ViewModel navigate to a different ViewModel?*
Can I simply call `Navigate` from inside the `Initialize` method?
Should I `Close` the current ViewModel before navigating to the 'substitute' screen?
Any concerns regarding the back stack?
Can local data be passed via the `Navigate` to the substitute screen?

I have seen [MvvmCross : ViewModel Navigation in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020587/mvvmcross-viewmodel-navigation-in-code), but that was 3.5 years ago, before 5.x.

Thank you,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You have different approaches to address this but first of all I'd recommend you to look to the new [Navigation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation).

1. Get the data that determines the decision concerning to which ViewModel you want to navigate before the navigation occurs. So you just navigate to the correct ViewModel depending on your data *(easier approach)*
2. As you mention (if you can't get your data before) on your `Initialize` get the data and then navigate to the ViewModel you want. Regarding closing the current ViewModel you can do that right afterwards or you can close it later (when you close the "substitute" ViewModel you also close the one in the middle) in the presenter. This is done by using a [PresentationHint](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/presenters/view-presenters?scroll=827) so that you can then (in your platform presenter) close the corresponding ViewModel.

HIH

Comment: Hi @fmaccaroni, 1.  I am so new to Android development that I have never seen anything older than 5.x.  2.  Adopting a framework means I must adopt the design patterns as well as the coding techniques imposed by the framework.  3. When MvvmCross 'suggests' doing heavy lifting in `Initialize`, where else can it be done without impacting performance?  4. Is it 'acceptable' to keep dozens, but not hundreds, of rows stored in a singleton, available to all the ViewModels?  Essentially an in-memory database?  5. Will calling `Navigate` from inside `Initialize` break anything?   Thx, M.

Comment: Hi, 3) here https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/viewmodel-lifecycle?scroll=226.39999389648438 you have the whole ViewModel lifecycle. As it suggests, you should all the heavy lifting in `Initialize` because it's a Task so it will be done in background without blocking the main thread and freezing the UI. 4) Yes that wouldn't be a problem if the model you are storing is not too heavy, if it is I'd recommend you to use Sqlite or Akavache as a light database.

Comment: 5) It should'nt break anything, you just need to be careful with the backstack because you will still have the view in the middle from where you call the `Navigate`. So make sure you close it when you close the next one if you need it

Comment: I am using Sqlite as the actual database storage mechanism.  I will experiment with both solutions, and report back with the results.  Thank you, Marc.